# How to keep long captions in the list of figures section in thesis?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, captions

I have long captions in my figures.

And I am using this packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[
top    = 2.75cm,
bottom = 2.50cm,
left   = 3.00cm,
right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

But in the 'List of Figures' section, the entire caption is shown in one line beyond the page margin. It is taking only one line for each figure caption. Therefore it is cutting the rest of the caption for each figure.

How to set multiple caption lines in the 'List of Figures' section with hyperlink ?

Comment: Welcome to SE. You aren't showing any code that displays the problem. Also, your code isn't compilable since it's missing the `document` environment, and some of the packages in this code are probably unrelated to the problem. Please about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and update your question. Thank you.

Comment: Aside from setspace, I don't see anything that might make a caption unbreakable.  You must be putting formatting commands inside the caption itself.  Use the "short caption" argument and \protect any macros.